# Filtering Exactly Same String Returns 0

Tags: r, string, filter, character

I have customer rentals data based on region. I want to filter a specific, I copy region name from data and still returns 0 rows.

```
Rentals[Rentals$Region == "Paris",]
```

I can't understand what is the problem and how to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Check if there is leading/lagging spaces `Rentals[trimws(Rentals$Region) == "Paris",]` (A reproducible example with `dput` would be better)

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. Do a `dput(data)` on your data. If your data is too big, do a `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: @akrun  It worked. I use this code: `Rentals$Region <- trimws(Rentals$Region)`  and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue would be in having leading/lagging spaces in strings.  It can be resolved with `trimws` that removes the white space from both ends (if any).

```
Rentals[trimws(Rentals$Region) == "Paris",]
```